# take assertion with redux-saga-test-plan that takes a function as pattern gives 'take effects do not match' error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

I want to test a saga that yields a `take` effect which takes a function as pattern, e.g.

```
export function* mySaga(myAction: {
  type: string;
}): Generator<TakeEffect, boolean, { type: string }> {
  const { type: actionType } = (yield take(
    (action: any) => action.type === myAction.type,
  )) as { type: string };
  return actionType === myAction.type;
}
```

with a test that looks like:

```
it('Should test mySaga', () => {
  testSaga(mySaga, { type: 'myActionType' }).next().take().next().finish();
});
```

but I get the following error:

```
SagaTestError: 
Assertion 1 failed: take effects do not match

Expected
--------
{ '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
  combinator: false,
  type: 'TAKE',
  payload: { pattern: '*' } }

Actual
------
{ '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
  combinator: false,
  type: 'TAKE',
  payload: { pattern: [Function] } }
```

I have not been able to find how to assert the a take effect that takes a function pattern instead of a string.  Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you pass an anonymous function to `take` effect creator. We can't get this anonymous function in the test case using the module requiring.

You can use [inspect](http://redux-saga-test-plan.jeremyfairbank.com/unit-testing/general-assertions.html) general assertions helper.

> If your saga yields a nondeterministic type of value or something not easily covered by the effect assertions or other general assertions, then you can use `inspect` to retrieve the actual yielded value and perform your own assertions with your favorite assertion library.

So that we can get the returned effect of `yield take((action: any) => action.type === myAction.type)`. Then, assert this effect.

E.g. (using jestjs as testing framework)

`saga.ts`:

```
import { TakeEffect, take } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export function* mySaga(myAction: { type: string }): Generator<TakeEffect, boolean, { type: string }> {
  const { type: actionType } = (yield take((action: any) => action.type === myAction.type)) as { type: string };
  console.log('actionType: ', actionType);
  return actionType === myAction.type;
}
```

`saga.test.ts`:

```
import { testSaga } from 'redux-saga-test-plan';
import { TakeEffect } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { mySaga } from './saga';

describe('63523200', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    testSaga(mySaga, { type: 'myActionType' })
      .next()
      .inspect<TakeEffect>((yieldedValue) => {
        expect(yieldedValue.payload.pattern).toEqual(expect.any(Function));
        // test this anonymous function
        expect((yieldedValue.payload.pattern as Function)({ type: 'myActionType' })).toBeTruthy();
        expect((yieldedValue.payload.pattern as Function)({ type: 'hisActionType' })).toBeFalsy();
      })
      .next({ type: 'otherActionType' })
      .isDone();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/63523200/saga.test.ts
  63523200
    ✓ should pass (23 ms)

  console.log
    actionType:  otherActionType

      at src/stackoverflow/63523200/saga.ts:5:11

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 saga.ts  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.809 s, estimated 3 s
```